# Retornar mensagem para a tela de cadastro

Tags: php, html

Galera, sou iniciante no PHP e preciso de uma ajuda.

Tenho um cadastro.html que possui alguns campos que chama o cadastro.php que insere os dados no banco de dados e mostra a mensagem se foi inserido com sucesso ou não.

Como faço para aparecer essa mensagem na tela de cadastro?

Tô tentando fazer da seguinte forma, quando clico no botão de "Cadastrar" vai para o cadastro.php e retorna para o cadastro.html com a mensagem de retorna (se foi inserido no banco de dados ou se foi inserido com sucesso).

Alguém tem alguma luz para me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você quer fazer ele mostrar uma mensagem quando foi inserido, você pode fazer assim

```
echo '<script> alert ("Quantidade alterada com sucesso!"); location.href=("cadastro.php")</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

substitua tudo por uma pagina .php, com isso você consegue trabalhar seu html e php  em um único arquivo.

ex.:

```
<?php

if(count($_POST)){
$variavel = $POST["variavel"];

//sua requisição via banco de dados

//se for ok, você retorna a mensagem
}

?>

//seu codigo html aqui
```

---

qualquer duvida posta os arquivos aqui

Comment: E como faz para não inserir os dados quando carrega a página?
http://prntscr.com/lkite9
Toda vez q atualizo a página ele insere dados em brancos no banco de dados além de ficar com esses erros...

Answer (score 0):

Um arquivo `HTML` é estático, não tem como montá-lo usando informações que você obteve no `PHP`. Para isso você precisa de um `template engine`, que por acaso, PHP já é um.

Para fins de organização seria melhor você ter algo como `cadastro_controller.php` e `cadastro.php`. Um arquivo PHP pode conter tanto código PHP, como HTML, então você pode usar cadastro.php para montar seu HTML, e ter acesso a mensagem do PHP simultaneamente.

Eu gostaria de escrever como fazer isso aqui, mas honestamente, o processo não é tão trivial. Você pode usar o `require "controler.php"` dentro do cadastro_controller.php trazer sua página ao ambiente em que você tem acesso ao resultado do cadastro, mas isso é um hack que não se escala bem em grandes projetos. É possível utilizar frameworks para esse processo, `Laravel` e `CodeIgnater` são bastante populares.

No final do processo, você terá seu cadastro.php parecido com

```
<html>
...
<p><?= $menssagem ?></p>
<a>Clique aqui para realizar um novo cadastro</a>
<a>Clique aqui para listar os automóveis</a>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie sua página que de formulário como arquivo php: cadastro.php
Envie as informações do formulário para outra página php: cadastro-insere.php por exemplo
Na página cadastro-insere.php envie a informação para o banco de dados.
Faça uma verificação da inserção e caso inserido crie uma session da mensagem de sucesso.

```
session_start();

if(cadastroInserido()){
  $_SESSION['inserido']="Cadastro inserido com sucesso!";
}
```

depois crie um header para voltar para página de cadastro.php

```
header("location:cadastro.php);
die();
```

na página de cadastro.php faça a leitura da session e depois a desvincule

```
if(isset($_SESSION['inserido'])){
echo $_SESSION['inserido'];
unset($_SESSION['inserido']);
}
```

acho que é uma das formas de fazer